# Banco usando vetor e struct em c

Tags: c, array, struct

Gente eu preciso fazer um programa onde eu salvo dados de cliente e contas, estou tentando salvar os dados da struct em um vetor (foi pedido desse modo) porém nao estou conseguindo sair do lugar, não sei oque pode estar errado, alguém teria alguma luz de como resolver isso?

Um outro pequeno problema seria na linha 52 onde não estou conseguindo utilizar o gets para o usuário poder digitar o nome dando espaço entre as letras, já que o scanf para após identificar um espaço em branco

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//ARMAZENAR EM ESTRUTURA E UNIOES
typedef union CPF_CNPJ cpf_cnpj;
union CPF_CNPJ{
    int cpfOUcnpj[14];
};

typedef struct Cliente cl;
struct Cliente{
    char nome[50];
    int RG[10];
    char endereco[50];
    int telefone[11];
    float renda[20];
    int tipo_cliente[1]; //1-private, 2-alta renda, 3-varejo
    cpf_cnpj tipoPessoa; //numa união o cpf ou cnpj do
       // cliente que pode ser uma pessoa física ou jurídica.
};
typedef struct Dados_Contas dc;
struct Dados_Contas{
    int Numero_Conta[6]; //deve ser unico e gerado pelo programa
    int Agencia[5];
    float Saldo_Conta[20];
    char Tipo_Conta[20];
    struct Cliente Titulares; // titulares (deve estar vinculado aos clientes cadastrados)
    int rg_titular;

};
void Cadastro_Conta (dc conta[], int qtd_cl, int num){
    int i, titular;

    for (i=0;i<=qtd_cl;i++){
    printf("O seguinte numero foi selecionado para sua conta:  %d \n", num);
    printf("Digite ele novamente para confirmar: \n"); scanf("%d", &conta[i].Numero_Conta);
    printf("Agencia: \n"); scanf("%d", &conta[i].Agencia);
    printf("Saldo da conta: \n"); scanf("%f", &conta[i].Saldo_Conta);
    printf("Tipo da conta: \n"); scanf("%s", &conta[i].Tipo_Conta);
    printf("Digite o RG do titular: \n"); scanf("%d", &conta[i].rg_titular);

    }
      // titulares


}

void Cadastro_Cliente (cl cliente[], int qtd_cl){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=qtd_cl;i++){
    printf("Nome: \n"); gets(Cliente[i].nome); //scanf("%s", &cliente[i].nome);
    printf("RG: \n"); scanf("%d", &cliente[i].RG);
    getchar();
    printf("Endereco: \n"); gets(Cliente[i].endereco); //scanf("%s", &cliente[i].endereco);
    printf("Telefone: \n"); scanf("%d", &cliente[i].telefone);
    printf("Renda: \n"); scanf("%f", &Cliente[i].renda);
    printf("Tipo de cliente: \n 1- Private: Superior a 1M \n 2- Alta renda: acima de 100mil \n 3- Publico geral \n"); scanf("%d", &cliente[i].tipo_cliente);
    printf("Cpf ou CNPJ: \n"); scanf("%d", &cliente[i].tipoPessoa);
    }
}

int main()
{
    //variaveis
    int Menu0,Menu1=0, Menu2=0, Menu3=0;
    int qtd_cl=0;
    int i=0;
    cl cadastro_cl[1000];
    dc conta[1000];
    srand(time(NULL)); //para o valor do numero da conta nao repetir
    //rand()%100000;

    //MENU
    do{
        printf("    MENU \n Digite um dos numeros abaixo: \n 1- Inserir \n 2- Imprimir \n 3- Atualizar \n 4- Deposito \n 5- Saque \n 6- Pix \n 0- Sair \n");
        scanf("%d", &Menu0);
        system("cls || clear");

        switch(Menu0){
    // 1- inserir
    case 1:
        printf("Voce deseja: \n 1- Inserir Nova Conta \n 2- Inserir Novo Cliente \n");
        scanf("%d", &Menu1);
        if(Menu1==1){ // chamada para nova conta
            int num=0;
            num= rand()%100000;

            Cadastro_Conta(conta, qtd_cl, num);


        } else if(Menu1==2){ // chamada para novo cliente
            Cadastro_Cliente(cadastro_cl ,qtd_cl);
        } else printf("ERRO!");

                //Mensagens de confirmacao para o usuario
        int x=0;
        if(Menu1==2){x=0;
            qtd_cl=qtd_cl+1;
            printf("Cadastro de Cliente realizado com sucesso! \n Digite 1 para retornar ao menu principal \n");
            scanf("%d", &x);
            if(x==1){
                system("cls || clear");
            }
        } else if(Menu1==1){x=0;
            printf("Cadastro da conta realizado com sucesso! \n Digite 1 para retornar ao menu principal\n");
            scanf("%d", &x);
            if(x==1){
                system("cls || clear");
            }
        }

        break;

    //2- imprimir
    case 2:
        printf("Voce deseja: \n 1- Imprimir dados de uma conta \n 2- Imprimir dados de um cliente \n 3- Lista de clientes de uma agencia \n 4- Lista de Contas por tipo de uma agencia \n");
        scanf("%d", &Menu2);
        if(Menu2==1){ // chamada imprimir dados de uma conta
            // ?????????????????????????????????????????????????

        } else if(Menu2==2){ // chamada para Imprimir dados de um cliente
            // ?????????????????????????????????????????????????

        } else if(Menu2==3){ // chamada para Lista de clientes de uma agencia
            for(i=0; i<=qtd_cl;i++){
                printf("Nome: \n %s \n" , cadastro_cl[i].nome);
                printf("RG: \n %d \n", cadastro_cl[i].RG);
                printf("Endereco: \n %s \n", cadastro_cl[i].endereco);
                printf("Telefone: \n %d \n", cadastro_cl[i].telefone);
                printf("Renda: \n %f \n", cadastro_cl[i].renda);
                printf("Tipo de cliente:\n %d \n" , cadastro_cl[i].tipo_cliente);
                printf("Cpf ou CNPJ: \n %d \n", cadastro_cl[i].tipoPessoa);
                system("cls || clear");
            }

        } else if(Menu2==4){ // chamada para Lista de Contas por tipo de uma agencia
            // ?????????????????????????????????????????????????

        }else printf("ERRO!");
        system("cls || clear");
        break;

    //3- Atualizar
    case 3:
        printf("Voce deseja: \n 1- Atualizar dados de um cliente \n 2- Atualizar dados de uma conta \n");
        scanf("%d", &Menu3);
        if(Menu3==1){ // chamada para atualizar dados de um cliente
                //NAO PODE MUDAR CPF
            // ?????????????????????????????????????????????????

        } else if(Menu3==2){ // chamada para atualizar dados de uma conta
            //NAO PODE MUDAR AGENCIA, NUMERO DA CONTA E TIPO
            // ?????????????????????????????????????????????????

        }else printf("ERRO!");
        system("cls || clear");
        break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em relação ao problema do espaço use fgets em vez de scanf.

Exemplo:
fgets(nome, 20, stdin);

Comment: deu certo, agora o meu problema se resume na hora que printa, as string ele esta printando porem oq nao é string ele nao printa

Comment: `
Voce deseja:
 1- Inserir Nova Conta
 2- Inserir Novo Cliente
2
Nome:
thiago s
RG:
5858585
Endereco:
rua m
Telefone:
191919
Renda:
1919
Tipo de cliente:
 1- Private: Superior a 1M
 2- Alta renda: acima de 100mil
 3- Publico geral
1
Cpf ou CNPJ:
20202020
Cadastro de Cliente realizado com sucesso!
 Digite 1 para retornar ao menu principal
`

Comment: Nome:
 thiago s
RG:
 6159604
Endereco:
 rua m
Telefone:
 6159696
Renda:
 0.000000
Tipo de cliente:
 6159820
Cpf ou CNPJ:
 5683472
Nome:

RG:
 6159932
Endereco:

Telefone:
 6160024
Renda:
 0.000000
Tipo de cliente:
 6160148
Cpf ou CNPJ:
 5683472 
.............dai ele printa isso e ainda duplica